# HttpURLConnection to php but no mysql post?

Tags: java, php, mysql, http

I am attempting to construct an URL through my java program that will send the URL to my php server, therefore inserting a row into my mysql database. I am able to manually send the URL (through my browser address bar) to my php server and successfully insert a row into my table.

However, when I construct the URL in my java program and attempt to send the request to the php server I am not inserting any rows. What is weird about this is that the url the java program constructs works when I manually put it in my address bar. I do get errors in my php error log, but from what I can tell everything looks fine.

Anything and everything helps, thank you.

Java:

```
    public void updateDB() throws IOException {


      final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
      final String POST_URL = "https://example.website/php/php.php?";
      final String POST_PARAMS = "charName=" + "\"myname\"" + "&logType=" + "\"Magic_logs\"" + "&magicPrice=" + pricePerMagicLog + "&yewPrice=" + pricePerYewLog + "&totalWealth="+ totalWealth;

    URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);


    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();


    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }

    println(POST_URL+POST_PARAMS);
```

}

php:

```
<?php require_once('muleconnect.php');
$charName = $_GET['charName'];
$logType = $_GET['logType'];
$magicPrice = $_GET['magicPrice'];
$yewPrice = $_GET['yewPrice'];
$totalWealth = $_GET['totalWealth'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table(char_name, log_type, magic_log_price, 
yew_log_price, total_wealth)
VALUES ($charName, $logType, $magicPrice, $yewPrice, $totalWealth)";


$query = $muleconnection->query($sql);
echo 'OK..';

?>
```

php error log:

```
[08-Oct-2017 14:00:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: charName in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php.php on line 4
[08-Oct-2017 14:00:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: logType in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php.php on line 5
[08-Oct-2017 14:00:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: magicPrice in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php.php on line 6
[08-Oct-2017 14:00:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: yewPrice in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php.php on line 7
[08-Oct-2017 14:00:47 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: totalWealth in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php.php on line 8
```

Successfully constructed url string (that works manually, not programtically)

```
https://example.website/php/php.php?charName=%22example_name%22&logType=%22Magic%20logs%22&magicPrice=1174&yewPrice=340&totalWealth=7145753
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing request with `POST`.

```
URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

But retrieving it with `GET`

```
$charName = $_GET['charName'];
$logType = $_GET['logType'];
$magicPrice = $_GET['magicPrice'];
$yewPrice = $_GET['yewPrice'];
$totalWealth = $_GET['totalWealth'];
```

And also here

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(char_name, log_type, magic_log_price, 
yew_log_price, total_wealth)
```

I think, `table` should be a actual `<<table_name>>`. Also, consider using prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you much, I will try this out later tonight and hopefully it works out. As far as the table name goes, I just put that as an example, my actual table name was editted out.

Comment: changing the GET to POST in my php file worked. Thank you! Upvoted and best answered.